# reformatting and cleaning CSV file with curly braces matching across distinct lines

Tags: regex, awk, text-processing

I would like to reformat a pure ascii file, test.txt, containing (just a sample of 10 lines out of several hundred):

```
{0.91, 0.87, -69.79, 
  -0.3149, 0.05}, {0.9392, 
      1.089, 69, -0.31, 
      0.052}, {-0.8768, 0.7025, 
      69.80, -0.314, 0.053}, 
     {0.930, -1.2638750861516, 69.79, 
      0.314, 0.05301}, {0.9367, 
      -1.368063705085268, 69.79962, -0.31, 
      0.052}, {0.946, -1.644, 
      69.7, 0.3, 0.052}
```

to a final file, test_processed.txt, containing (for the same sample):

```
0.91, 0.87, -69.79, -0.3149, 0.05 
0.9392, 1.089, 69, -0.31, 0.052 
-0.8768, 0.7025, 69.80, -0.314, 0.053 
0.930, -1.2638750861516, 69.79, 0.314, 0.05301 
0.9367, -1.368063705085268, 69.79962, -0.31, 0.052} 
0.946, -1.644, 69.7, 0.3, 0.052
```

That is, a plain CSV file, with each line containing exactly the five fields within the original pairs of matched braces.

I tried to fiddle a little with gawk and regex'es, but wasn't able to figure out how to manage this; I have the feeling that tweaking with awk's variables RS and ORS might help, but could not forge ahead...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `gnu-awk`, you may use this awk using `RS` to match anything between`{...}` and then remove starting `{`, ending `}` and newlines:

```
awk -v RS='{[^}]+}' 'RT{gsub(/^{|}$|\n */, "", RT); print RT}' file
```

```
0.91, 0.87, -69.79, -0.3149, 0.05
0.9392, 1.089, 69, -0.31, 0.052
-0.8768, 0.7025, 69.80, -0.314, 0.053
0.930, -1.2638750861516, 69.79, 0.314, 0.05301
0.9367, -1.368063705085268, 69.79962, -0.31, 0.052
0.946, -1.644, 69.7, 0.3, 0.052
```

**How it works:**

- `-v RS='{[^}]+}'`: Sets record separator a match for `{...}`
- `RT`: Checks if `RT` is not empty. `RT` is set as the string from input, matched by `RS` pattern.
- `{...}` is action block in awk
- `gsub(/^{|}$|\n */, "", RT)`: Removes starting `{`, ending `}` and line break followed by 0 or more spaces from `RT`
- `print RT`: prints modified `RT`

Comment: It did work; thank you! Could you please explain a bit the logic of the command?

Comment: I will add more explanation in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following with GNU `awk`, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk -v RS="" -v FS="[}{]" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2){gsub(/\n+ +/," ",$i);print $i}}' Input_file
```

output will be as follows.

```
0.91, 0.87, -69.79,  -0.3149, 0.05
0.9392,  1.089, 69, -0.31,  0.052
-0.8768, 0.7025,  69.80, -0.314, 0.053
0.930, -1.2638750861516, 69.79,  0.314, 0.05301
0.9367,  -1.368063705085268, 69.79962, -0.31,  0.052
0.946, -1.644,  69.7, 0.3, 0.052
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='{[^}]+}' 'RT{$0=RT; gsub(/[{}]/,""); $1=$1; print}' file
0.91, 0.87, -69.79, -0.3149, 0.05
0.9392, 1.089, 69, -0.31, 0.052
-0.8768, 0.7025, 69.80, -0.314, 0.053
0.930, -1.2638750861516, 69.79, 0.314, 0.05301
0.9367, -1.368063705085268, 69.79962, -0.31, 0.052
0.946, -1.644, 69.7, 0.3, 0.052
```